# Show formatted date in f.text_field if present, else placeholder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, date-format, form-helpers

The following code works to show the date only if it's present:

```
f.text_field :published_at, placeholder: "E.g. 12 Sep 2014", value: @post.try(:published_at)
```

But how would I format it?

This is how I'd format it if I knew that the date is present:

```
value: @post.published_at.strftime("%e %b %Y")
```

Comment: are you about `@post.try(:published_at).try(:strftime, "%e %b %Y")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap that around a helper function to change the format

```
f.text_field :published_at, placeholder: "E.g. 12 Sep 2014", value: custom_format(@post.try(:published_at))
```

some_helper.rb

```
def custom_format(date)
  date ? date.strftime("%e %b %Y") : nil
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a simple method that returns the date in your preferred format?

```
class YourModel
  def formatted_published_at
    published_at.strftime("%e %b %Y") if published_at?
  end
end
```

You will probably use it in other views too, apart from the form.